# Gráficos Animados - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

Olá, preciso fazer um gráfico animado que mostre os 10 primeiros estados.

Estou tentando, mas está mostrando os 14 primeiros e não está na ordem do maior para o menor.

Segue abaixo o código utilizado:

```
# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(gifski)

# Agrupando por CBO, UF e Ano
dGrafico <- SuperRais %>% select(CBO.Ocupação.2002,uf,ano) %>% 
            group_by(CBO.Ocupação.2002,uf,ano) %>%
            summarise(qtd=n())


iAno <- 2010
lCbo <- unique(as.character(dGrafico$CBO.Ocupação.2002))
iCbo <- lCbo[1]

# Gerando gráficos por CBO e Ano
for (iCbo in lCbo) {
  dGraficoA <- data.frame()

  for (i in 2010:2016) {
      dGrafico2 <- dGrafico %>% filter(ano == i & CBO.Ocupação.2002 == iCbo) %>% arrange(desc(qtd))
      dGraficoA <- bind_rows(dGrafico2[1:10,],dGraficoA)
  }

  # Ordenando do maior, para o menor  
  dGraficoA <- dGraficoA %>% arrange(desc(qtd))

  # Gerando Gráfico animado 
  g <- ggplot(dGraficoA, aes(x=reorder(uf, qtd), y=qtd)) +
             geom_bar(stat='identity') +
             coord_flip() +
             transition_time(ano) +
             # view_follow(fixed_x = TRUE) +
             shadow_mark() +
             enter_grow()  +
             enter_fade()  +
             labs(title = paste0("Ano: {frame_time} - ",iCbo))
       anim_save(paste0('g_',iCbo,'.gif'),animation = g) # Salvando animacao em .gif
}
```

São 8 gráficos (um para cada CBO) que mostre a quantidade de CBO por UF com o passar dos anos. As UF devem estar por ordem, da maior pra menor.

Segue como está ficando: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqf7U.jpg

```
>dput(head(dGrafico, 10))
structure(list(CBO.Ocupação.2002 = structure(c(201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L, 201L), .Label = c( "842305", "991410", "991415", "991416", "322310", "223162", "223135", "223152", "111235", "223119"), class = "factor"), uf = c("AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AL", "AL", "AL"), ano = c(2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L), qtd = c(94L, 96L, 90L, 73L, 75L, 73L, 68L, 16L, 16L, 14L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(CBO.Ocupação.2002 = structure(c(201L, 201L), .Label = c( "842230", "848410", "848415", "848420", "848605", "861120", "910120", "911125", "911130", "911135" )
```

Mas eu tenho 30 UF diferentes, 7 ano diferentes e 8 CBO diferentes

Comment: Por favor, compartilhe o `dput(head(SuperRais , 30))` ou dados semelhantes para que possamos reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Editei o post com a informação.

Comment: Mas elas estão estão em ordem.... Não sei se a ordem está usando os dados de todos os anos, ou apenas o último ano. Você quer algo diferente disso?

Comment: Não estão em ordem não, vide exemplo que postei. Com o passar dos anos um estado vai "passando"  o outro e o eixo y não é alterado. Deveria estar organizado pela quantidade de CBO. Pode ver que no ínicio tem estados com quantidade 0 em cima de estados que já possuem valores.

Comment: A ordem que eu gostaria seria de acordo com os anos, conforme passa o ano, o estado deveria atualizar a ordem. Não sei se estou conseguindo ser claro.

Comment: Agora entendi. Assim que puder vejo a questão

Comment: ok, muito obrigado !

Comment: Isso que eu queria fazer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tjNXULSlFio

Comment: Seu dput não está funcionando...